# Flattening a list of data frames into one data frame with purrr::flatten_dfr

Tags: r, list, purrr, flatten

```
library(tidyverse)

test_list <- list(a = data.frame("fruits" = fruit[1:10],
                                 "letters" = letters[1:10],
                                 "numbers" = rnorm(10)),
                  b = data.frame("fruits" = fruit[1:12],
                                 "letters" = letters[1:12],
                                 "numbers" = rnorm(12)),
                  c = data.frame("fruits" = fruit[1:7],
                                 "letters" = letters[1:7],
                                 "numbers" = rnorm(7)),
                  d = data.frame("fruits" = fruit[1:12],
                                 "letters" = letters[1:12],
                                 "numbers" = rpois(12, 2)))
```

I have a list of data frames with the same structure of columns but with different number of rows in each df. I just want to flatten them in to one data frame. I figured I could just use something like `purrr::flatten_dfr()`:

`flatteneddf <- flatten_dfr(test_list)`

However this throws an issue with the row length of each df:

`Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 4 must be length 10, not 12`

I know there are many other options available to flatten list of dfs but I just want to know why this option isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- bind_rows(test_list)
```

I'm not sure there is a way you can solve this with `flatten_dfr`.

For example, even if you'd have the same length of all dataframes, `flatten_dfr` would just return one of them.

If the column names would be different and length the same, `flatten_dfr` would bind those with completely different names, therefore mimicking the behaviour of `bind_cols`.

Perhaps someone else has a specific use case for `flatten_dfr`, but I think in the end what you'll end up using is either `bind_rows` or `bind_cols`.

Comment: I think it should be `library(dplyr)` instead of tidyverse.

Comment: `tidyverse` is fine and I used it as OP is using it. Loading `dplyr` would be sufficient of course.